# Run GDB command line multiple times

Tags: linux, python, debugging, gdb

Due to my mother language is not English. So, excuse me for this bad introduction of my question. I would explain what I need through figure shown below.

[image: .gdbinit files inside the target folder]
As you can see, we have a folder which contains n `.gdbinit` files ( n=2000 or more).

strictly speaking, I attempt to run all of these `.gdbinit` files by using a loop statement in GDB. Is it possible in gdb alone, or I should modify my gdb to support another language like python, and then write loop statement in gdb by using python syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to keep it simple, write a small shell script to prepare your  `~/.gdbinit` file, eg `find . -name '*.gdbinit'|sort|sed 's/^/source /' >~/.gdbinit`

Comment: I need more than 12000 tests. so, the .gdbinit file will contain 12000 line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I found the answer to my question.

Here is

we simply write an application in any language like java for example
and in that application, we generate a `.gdbinit` file (say trigger`.gdbinit`) which contains the following lines:

```
source file0.gdbinit

source file1.gdbinit

source file2.gdbinit

source file3.gdbinit

source file4.gdbinit
```

and so on.

Now, in gdb we just type this command,

```
(gdb) source trigger.gdbinit
```

and it is enough to execute all `file0,1,2,....n.gdbinit` 
just by single line.